# Extract text from screen in python

Tags: python, screen

Is there a library etc for extracting text from a *png* bitmap screen shot?

It is for a automizer and would (for example) be able to read buttons etc. I've checked Tesseract, but it seems to be made for pictures, not computer screen fonts.

Comment: It's really complicated, because each app draws the screen itself. What you want is screen-capturing and text detecting.

Comment: As it is a bitmap it shouldn't be that complicated as there are no noise? I'm just wondering if there is anyone that already done it.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no OCR library specifically designed for recognizing screen fonts in screen captures. Some OCR libraries may be better at this than others, but I don't think that's ever been anyone's primary goal. (And it's not quite as simple as you probably think—the text engines on OS X, Windows, and most *nix programs use vector fonts, allow the fonts to be customized, anti-alias them, do fancy things with color and transparency, etc., so it's not just a matter of "detect these 96 fixed bitmaps".) Anyway, have you actually _tried_ Tesseract, or just read the overview?

Comment: I've tried Tesseract and it didn't catch any characters. According to it's FAQ it filters out objects smaller than 10 pxs. 

Maybe I could tweak it somehow.

Comment: You could also hook into the target application, although this would require some reverse engineering if it isn't your application.

Answer (score 2):

If you're dealing with a small amount of possible matches (i.e.: you want to recognize two or three different buttons), the simplest way is to isolate those in a previous screenshot, save them to individual files, and then use some form of template matching, which is [quite easy in opencv](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/template_matching/template_matching.html).

If, however, you need to actually perform *recognition* of the button text, you're going to need a OCR engine. Tesseract is a good candidate, if you can [get it trained for your font](https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/wiki/TrainingTesseract3) (it's a lengthy process). As you mention, you'll *need* to do this if you're dealing with a small font, which tesseract is not originally trained to recognize. If you can't, there's a couple other engines usable in python around, like [Ocropus](https://code.google.com/p/ocropus/)

Comment: I've also been trying to do this same exact thing, and since training Tesseract frustrated me so much (long story) I've [written something simple from scratch](https://github.com/goncalopp/simple-ocr-opencv) </advertisement>